# How to find the selected element xpath using firebug function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, firebug

[firebug plugin](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js) or suggest me any other method for find the selected element xpath

Comment: Firepath plugin for Firebug. You can find it at https://addons.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

In the code you linked to it is the [`Xpath.getElementTreeXPath()`](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js#L29) function.

That function is called when you right-click an element within the *HTML* panel and choose *Copy XPath*.